# remove brackets from returned string

Tags: java, json, selenium, testing, ui-testing

I currently call a json within my selenium tests and they are returned in the form of [4534535], id like to remove the brackets and leave just 4534535 but the code im currently using doesnt seem to do that and i cant find a solution.

Currently im using

```
String[] tmp = response_body_string.split("[\\[\\]]");
String val2 = tmp[0];
val3 = val2.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

The response_body_string is what ive received back from the json (please not sometimes theres is a list of code returned thats why im using string[]
But it seems to be returning nothing, is the tmp[0] causing the issue?

Im tryign to use the code in another json and then pass the string of "4534535" on to the next one. Im able to use the code when theres more than one code number , for example [3343,221213] works fine because im using

```
String[] tmp = response_body_string.split(",");
tmp = tmp[1].split(",");
//Returns second game ID
String val2 = tmp[0];
val3 = val2.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

Comment: edit the question with a full example of the json you want to remove brackets and the outcome you want

Comment: I tried          val3 = val2.replaceAll("[\\\\p{Ps}\\\\p{Pe}]", "");
But seems to return nothing again

Comment: `"[123124321524]".replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");` will return 123124321524

Comment: this is an XY problem.  the question you really want answered is how to parse values from json... removing brackets with regexes is just an issue with the incorrect solution you are attempting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, You want to remove only the brackets and get only the number. You can use:

```
String[] tmp = response_body_string.split("[\\[\\]]");
String tmp = tmp[0].substring(1,tmp.length-1);
```

Hope I got you right.

edit:

If `response_body_string`is a string(I assume yes Because you are using String function), you can just do the substring to it. like that:

```
String Final = response_body_string.substring(1,response_body_string.length-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close to the answer on your last line. You could use `replaceAll()` to remove everything except digits AND commas and then do the split.

```java
    String[] tmp = response_body_string.replaceAll("[^0-9,]", "").split(",");
```

Though I would recommend you just parse it as JSON to avoid any unpleasant surprises. For example you could use fasterxml's `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`

```java
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<Integer> tmp = mapper.readValue(response_body_string, new TypeReference<List<Integer>>() {});
```